# JavaFX project works in IntelliJ, but not when I clone from a git remote repository and run 'gradle wrapper' and './gradlew run'

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, javafx, groovy

all! Three other people and I have recently completed a Java project, which is a recreation of the game Pokemon. Here is a link to the project:
https://github.com/Pirate-Hunter-Zoro/Pokemon

The following screen recording should show that the project runs successfully on IntelliJ: https://screencast-o-matic.com/watch/c3lXbNVvrqX

However, when I try to clone this project from Git, and run 'gradle wrapper' and then './gradlew run', while the application does launch, I cannot make it past the intro screen, as this video shows:
https://somup.com/c3lXbRww2Y

Finally, here is the resulting error message:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at javafx.fxml@19/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1857)
        at javafx.fxml@19/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1724)
        at javafx.base@19/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
        at javafx.base@19/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:234)
        at javafx.base@19/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
        at javafx.base@19/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
        at javafx.base@19/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
        at javafx.base@19/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at javafx.base@19/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at javafx.base@19/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at javafx.base@19/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at javafx.base@19/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at javafx.base@19/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
        at javafx.base@19/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
        at javafx.base@19/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
        at javafx.graphics@19/javafx.scene.Scene$ClickGenerator.postProcess(Scene.java:3599)
        at javafx.graphics@19/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3903)
        at javafx.graphics@19/javafx.scene.Scene.processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1887)
        at javafx.graphics@19/javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2620)
        at javafx.graphics@19/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:411)
        at javafx.graphics@19/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:301)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
        at javafx.graphics@19/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:450)
        at javafx.graphics@19/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:424)
        at javafx.graphics@19/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:449)
        at javafx.graphics@19/com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:551)
        at javafx.graphics@19/com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
        at javafx.graphics@19/com.sun.glass.ui.mac.MacView.notifyMouse(MacView.java:127)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at com.sun.javafx.reflect.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:77)
        at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at javafx.base@19/com.sun.javafx.reflect.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
        at javafx.fxml@19/com.sun.javafx.fxml.MethodHelper.invoke(MethodHelper.java:84)
        at javafx.fxml@19/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1852)
        ... 27 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URL: Invalid URL or resource not found
        at javafx.graphics@19/javafx.scene.image.Image.validateUrl(Image.java:1138)
        at javafx.graphics@19/javafx.scene.image.Image.<init>(Image.java:628)
        at csci205_final_project@0.1-SNAPSHOT/org.Fearsome_Foursome.Application.Controllers.ArenaController.setUpNameSpriteHealth(ArenaController.java:190)
        at csci205_final_project@0.1-SNAPSHOT/org.Fearsome_Foursome.Application.HelloPokemon.loadScene(HelloPokemon.java:102)
        at csci205_final_project@0.1-SNAPSHOT/org.Fearsome_Foursome.Application.Controllers.MenuController.showArena(MenuController.java:108)
        at csci205_final_project@0.1-SNAPSHOT/org.Fearsome_Foursome.Application.Controllers.MenuController.setHard(MenuController.java:132)
        ... 38 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URL or resource not found
        at javafx.graphics@19/javafx.scene.image.Image.validateUrl(Image.java:1123)
```

Please let me know if there is any more information I should get a hold of and share!

Many thanks for any help anyone could offer!

I tried to clone a repository and use 'gradle wrapper' and './gradlew run', expecting the application to work. The application launches, but does not work.

Comment: Did you check the line that is throwing the exception? Does the image url look correct?

Comment: Yes, and interestingly it works perfectly when running in IntelliJ

Comment: When you run the application in IntelliJ, is your application being put on the module-path or the class-path (i.e., is your application in a _named_ module or an _unnamed_ module). I ask because I notice you're using a "schemeless" URL with your `Image` constructor call, which tends to break for modular applications due to encapsulated resources. If adding `opens Sprites;` (and probably similar _unconditional_ `opens` directives for every resource package) to your `module-info` file makes your code work, then likely that was the problem.